# wcheck-mode: Add buffer local dictionary?

Tags: spell-checking, flyspell

With `flyspell-mode`, one can maintain a buffer local dictionary. For example, I may middle-click *"stackexchange"* and select *Accept (buffer)*. This adds the word to the dictionary at the end of the buffer:

```
%  LocalWords:  stackexchange
```

It would be nice to have the same functionality with [wcheck-mode](https://github.com/tlikonen/wcheck-mode). Documentation for release 2014.6.21 contains [example code](https://github.com/tlikonen/wcheck-mode) for an *"Add to dictionary"* menu entry, but that's not buffer local.